# Use slice notation with collections.deque

Tags: python, slice, deque

How would you extract items 3..6 efficiently, elegantly and pythonically from the following `deque` without altering it:

```
from collections import deque
q = deque('',maxlen=10)
for i in range(10,20):
    q.append(i)
```

the [slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/good-primer-for-python-slice-notation/509295#509295) doesn't seem to work with `deque`...

Answer (score 99, accepted):

```
import itertools
output = list(itertools.islice(q, 3, 7))
```

For example:

```
>>> import collections, itertools
>>> q = collections.deque(xrange(10, 20))
>>> q
deque([10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19])
>>> list(itertools.islice(q, 3, 7))
[13, 14, 15, 16]
```

This should be more efficient the the other solutions posted so far. Proof?

```
[me@home]$ SETUP="import itertools,collections; q=collections.deque(xrange(1000000))"

[me@home]$ python -m timeit  "$SETUP" "list(itertools.islice(q, 10000, 20000))"
10 loops, best of 3: 68 msec per loop

[me@home]$ python -m timeit "$SETUP" "[q[i] for i in  xrange(10000, 20000)]"
10 loops, best of 3: 98.4 msec per loop

[me@home]$ python -m timeit "$SETUP" "list(q)[10000:20000]"
10 loops, best of 3: 107 msec per loop
```

Comment: Very nice. Since you have a full example, perhaps `q.extend(range(10, 20))` might be better.

Comment: @rm yes, `q.extend(..)` would be good. In fact, `q = deque(xrange(10,20))` should be used. I simply copied OP's example as is. Updated answer.

Answer (score 10):

I would prefer this, it's shorter so easier to read:

```
output = list(q)[3:6+1]
```

Comment: But it makes two copies of the `deque` (one full, one partial) instead of one partial copy. Not a problem if the `deque` is short, but it might be if it's long.

Comment: True, that.  But then, this isn't really a use-case for a `deque`.  The other solution creates a list for the `range`. I'd think of this like the `list(set(list))` hack to find unique elements of a list - elegant, and pretty, but maybe not the most efficient.

Comment: You could just substitute `xrange` for range though and it wouldn't create a list -- also, consider if you want a short slice of a long `deque` -- the partial list and / or range would be tiny, but the full copy would a problem.

Comment: Agreed. But like I said, a `deque` won't be the best choice of data-structure if you want to do something like that, with those constraints.

Answer (score 10):

This is an old question, but for any future travelers, the Python docs explicitly recommend using `rotate` for this:

> The rotate() method provides a way to implement deque slicing and deletion.

https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html

An implementation is relatively simple:

```
def slice_deque(d, start, stop, step):
    d.rotate(-start)
    slice = list(itertools.islice(d, 0, stop-start, step))
    d.rotate(start)
    return slice
```

Effectively the same as using `islice` directly, except that `rotate` is more efficient for skipping through to the starting point. On the other hand, it also temporarily modifies the deque, which could be a threadsafety concern.

Comment: Here's the link to the v3 documentation (the last paragraph in the section): https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#deque-recipes

Answer (score 6):

I'd add this as a new answer, to provide better formatting.

For simplicity, Shawn's answer is perfect, but if you often need to get a slice from `dequeue`, you might prefer to subclass it and add a `__getslice__` method.

```py
from collections import deque
from itertools import islice
class deque_slice(deque):
    def __new__(cls, *args):
        return deque.__new__(cls, *args)
    def __getslice__(self, start, end):
        return list(islice(self, start, end))
```

This won't support *setting* a new slice, but you can implement your own custom `__setslice__` method using the same concept.

**NOTE**: this is valid for Python <=2.* only. It's also worth noticing that, while `__getslice__` is [deprecated since python 2.0](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getslice__), the documentation still reports this for the latest 2.7 release:

> (However, built-in types in CPython currently still implement **`__getslice__()`**. Therefore, you have to override it in derived classes when implementing slicing.)

Comment: @Zeromatiker You're right, thanks for pointing that out. However, the note in the docs is still valid for python 2 (and we all know that it's still alive even now in mid-2020, no matter what): "built-in types in CPython currently still implement __getslice__(). Therefore, you have to override it in derived classes when implementing slicing."

Answer (score 6):

you can override the  `__getitem__` method and create a `SliceableDeque` using `islice`.

There are edge cases, you should consider (for example using negative slices doesn't work with `islice`).

here is what I have been using:

```
import itertools
from collections import deque

class SliceableDeque(deque):
    def __getitem__(self, s):
        try:
            start, stop, step = s.start or 0, s.stop or sys.maxsize, s.step or 1
        except AttributeError:  # not a slice but an int
            return super().__getitem__(s)
        try:  # normal slicing
            return list(itertools.islice(self, start, stop, step))
        except ValueError:  # incase of a negative slice object
            length = len(self)
            start, stop = length + start if start < 0 else start, length + stop if stop < 0 else stop
            return list(itertools.islice(self, start, stop, step))
```

Answer (score 3):

```
output = [q[i] for i in range(3,6+1)]
```

Comment: The slice properly also works if the slice length exceeds the container length (it will return less elements). This is not the case here