# First n element of deque

Tags: python

how do I get first n element of dequeue, and then n+1 to 2n element of dequeue and so on.

I know how to do it on list, but using the same method, I get:

```
from collections import deque
d = deque('ghi')
print d[:2]
```

I got the following:

```
$python main.py
deque(['g', 'h', 'i'])
3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 7, in <module>
    a = d[:2]
TypeError: sequence index must be integer, not 'slice'
```

Comment: Deques don't support slicing. I think that's because it wouldn't work as well as you'd expect, based on how they're stored, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `itertools`,

```
from collections import deque
import itertools

d = deque('ghi')
print (list(itertools.islice(d, 1, 3)))

# output,
['h', 'i']
```

Or if you want to print as a string,

```
print (''.join(itertools.islice(d, 1, 3)))

#output,
hi
```

Answer (score 0):

Try itertools.islice()

```
 deque_slice = collections.deque(itertools.islice(d, 0, 2))
```

Note that you can't use negative indices or step values with islice.

More details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10003143/how-to-slice-a-deque)