In python, is list(queue.queue) thread/process safe?
My understanding is that internals of Queue objects in python handle locking so that that you don't need to use locks externally just to call .put() or .get(). My question is am I covered by those same object internals if I want to display the contents of the queue by casting it as a list via list(queue) list(queue.queue)? Or, more generally, is there any conceivable operation using python queues that require the use of locks external to the queue object to ensure thread safety?
Example:
from queue import Queue
queue = Queue()
list(queue.queue)

Phrased another way, will I ever have to use
with lock_object:
    some_function(queue)

???

I don't think so. list() has to iterate over the queue. While individual operations are atomic, I don't think it will lock the queue for the entire loop.

Actually why don't ya tell us what you're trying to accomplish with this - In Zen of python:  "There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it." & "If the implementation is hard to explain, it's a bad idea." - You might have better design choice of what you're trying to do over one you're asking for, making this XY problem!

You can't determine what's in a queue (other than its size) without calling get() thereby, effectively, consuming its contents. There's no equivalent "peek" functionality. In other words, if you want a list of the queue's contents, you're going need to empty the queue

@nocomment I've updated my question to use proper syntax. What I meant was list(queue.queue) where the .queue is the attribute of the queue object. My question is whether or not accessing the queue in this fashion is process-safe and is done atomically (through locking or otherwise), where each element is grabbed before other processes can change its contents via .get() or .put().

It's unclear what you mean by "Queue". The only two standard Queue implementations I'm aware of cannot be iterated over, so "casting it as a list" just raises an exception:
>>> import queue
>>> q = queue.Queue()
>>> list(q)
Traceback (most recent call last):
    ...
TypeError: 'Queue' object is not iterable

>>> from multiprocessing import Queue
>>> q = Queue()
>>> list(q)
Traceback (most recent call last):
    ...
TypeError: 'Queue' object is not ierable

Whether you may ever need to do:
with lock_object:
    some_function(queue)

can't be answered based on what you've said so far. If, for example, your higher-level logic relies on putting the queue into (in effect) "read only" mode for some time, then, sure. You'll need a lock to ensure mutual exclusion between the reading and writing sides for the duration.
.put() and .get() on their own are already thread- and process- (in the case of multiprocessing.Queue) safe.
More than just that is not guaranteed by the docs, so can't be relied on even if it "appears to" work (which, if so, may be a reliable accident of the specific Python implementation you're using, or may be a fickle accident due to your simply not having yet bumped into a relevant race condition).
NEW QUESTION, NEW ANSWER
The question was edited to ask about list(queue.queue) instead. That falls under the earlier "accident of the specific Python implementation you're using", in two respects:

It's not documented that a Queue.queue object has a queue attribute. Python is a "consenting adults" language, and doesn't try to prevent you from using implementation details. But, if you do, you're on your own. The implementation may change at any time.
It so happens that list(deque) is thread-safe today (CPython 3.12.5), but that's not documented either. I only know that it is because I stared at the C implementation code. It may not be thread-safe in 3.12.6. More generally, CPython is moving toward a "no GIL" mode of operation, in which this kind of thing becomes much more likely to suffer races.

The bottom line doesn't change: .put() and .get() on their own are already thread- and process- (in the case of multiprocessing.Queue) safe. Nothing more than that is guaranteed. Really! ;-) Nothing. If you need more than just that much to be reliable across implementations and releases, you'll need to supply your own locks.

Ah, thanks @TimPeters, I had hoped it worked just like list(deque()), but I didn't actually test it. I edited my question. It looks like queue.queue returns a deque object representing the contents of the queue. My question is whether or not accessing the queue in this fashion is process-safe and is done atomically (through locking or otherwise), where each element is grabbed before other processes can change its contents via .get() or .put().

see new section at the bottom of my reply

Concerning an undocumented queue attribute, its usage is described in that high upvoted answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38350840/3440745

stackoverflow doesn't define the language - Python's docs define it. The answer I gave is correct. The referenced answer is "use at your own risk", regardless of whether it says so. Here are Python's docs, so check for yourself: https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html

@TimPeters, thanks for the explanation. If this is indeed just an implementation detail, it would seem there is no "safe" way to see a snapshot of a queue's contents from a particular process/thread without acquiring a lock, .get()-ing every item off the queue, displaying it in a list, and then writing them back on the queue, which seems woefully inefficient. Am I reading that right or did I miss something?

Bingo. What you describe was never an intended use case, and there is no official support for it. Note too that the current implementations of queue.Queue and multiprocessing.Queue are very different. The latter objects don't even have a queue attribute. today. All that said, I think it's unlikely that queue.Queue will ever change from using a deque bound to a queue attribute. But there is no guarantee of anything not promised in the docs.
